# Most efficient way to Spawn and destroy objects for endless runner game?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm currently very new to SFML and i was wonder what the most efficient way to spawn and destroy objects in a vector based on the camera position ? Currently I'm instantiating a vector of wall "points" which will be linked together after debugging. Should i be Creating and destroying them based on the the cam position or moving the already existing ones to the correct position ?

I also wouldn't mind some feedback on my code for this.

**Cave Chaos.cpp**

```
int main()
{
//get classes from CaveChaos.h
CaveChaos::Wall objWall;
CaveChaos::Player objPlayer;

//set render window size and name
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "CaveChaos");

//set the view
sf::View view1(sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f), sf::Vector2f(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y));

//create the player object as a triangle 
sf::CircleShape Player(20, 3);

//initialise random 
srand(time(0));

//sets the player position to a good position based on camera size
objPlayer.posx = window.getSize().x / 2;
objPlayer.posy = window.getSize().y / 1.1;

Player.setPosition(objPlayer.posx, objPlayer.posy);

//used to instantiate wall points
int locationsX[numofpoints];

//add random x values to locations
for (int i = 0; i < numofpoints; i++)
{
    locationsX[i] = (rand() % 50) + 1;      
}

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    //clear the window with black color
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    //calls wallspawn in Walls.cpp which creates the wall points
    WallSpawn(window, locationsX );

    //calls playermove in Player.cpp which move the player
    PlayerMove(window, Player);

    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    //set the player as the cam follow point
    view1.setCenter(Player.getPosition().x, Player.getPosition().y - objPlayer.posy / 3);
    //set the view to the player
    window.setView(view1);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Currently when i call WallSpawn() it loops through 10 objects and spawns them, would there be a way to spawn an infinite amount of objects instead ?

**Walls.cpp**

```
void WallSpawn(sf::RenderWindow& window, int locationsX[] )
{
//initiate random 
srand(time(0));

//class objects
CaveChaos::Wall objWall;
CaveChaos::Player objPlayer;

//creates a vector of circleshapes 
std::vector<sf::CircleShape> points;

//defines and circle of size 5
sf::CircleShape shape(5);

//loop through all of the points 
for (int i = 0; i < numofpoints; i++)
{   
    //set the shape position to the random variable from CaveChaos.cpp
    shape.setPosition(locationsX[i], objPlayer.posy + i * 55);

    //set shape color to green
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));

    // copy shape to vector
    points.push_back(shape);
}

// iterate through vector
for (std::vector<sf::CircleShape>::iterator it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
{
    //draw wall points on screen
    window.draw(*it);
}
}
```

What would be the best way to move or destroy these objects after they have been spawned ?

I want this last point to either get destroy or moved to the front when i go forward: 
[image: Position1]

and when i move forward something like this to happen:
[image: Position2]

If this method is completely wrong or i shouldn't be using this method at all please let me know.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Code Review

So first of all stackoverflow is not the right site for code review. If you seek for a complete review ask on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, here are some things I noticed:

1. Don't use `rand` or `srand`. If you want RNG use [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) (usually [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) or [`uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)).
2. Why are you using a native array for `locationsX`? `std::vector` seems much more reasonable.
3. Avoid frequent allocations inside performance critical loops (ex. you call `WallSpawn` each game loop iteration and `WallSpawn` itself creates a new vector `sf::CircleShape` each time which canbe avoided). More on that later.
4. Preallocate space for `std::vector` using `vector.reserve()` if you have an estimate of the final vector size.
5. Why do you do you have two event loops inside the window loop instead of just one?
6. Using `auto` instead of `std::vector<sf::CircleShape>::iterator` improves readability.

## Design

Usually a game loop looks like this:

1. polling window events and handling user input,
2. updating game state (reacting to input, applying physics, character movement, ...), and
3. drawing the new game state.

Your `WallSpawn` function, for example, shows how it shouldn't be done. You're generating new game entities (wall points) and then you draw them straight away in the same function.

I have limited expirience with SFML but I know that there is a [`sf::Drawable`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) base class which can be used for everything that needs to be drawn on the window. You don't have to use it but it's designed for easier OOP development. For example, you could create a type for your *wall points* or for the entire wall (depending on what you actually want to do with those points):

```
class WallPoint : public sf::Drawable 
{
public:
    WallPoint(int x, int y) :
        position(x, y), circle(x, y, 5)
    {
    }

    /*
     * Getter and setter for position 
     */

    void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const override
    {
        target.draw(circle);
    }

private:
    sf::Point position;
    sf::CircleShape circle;
};
```

And then keep a collection of those points in a variable outside of your game loop.

## Entity Management

Large games with thousands or millions of game entities (vehicles, trees, rocks, walls, weapons, ammo, projectiles, crowds, NPCs, ...) have the problem that they have to be very efficient when it comes to managing them. However, in your case with a few simple circle shapes, efficient management is not really a concern. Don't optimize if you don't have to.

You gave too little information about the game behavior to make a profund recommendation, so here is some guessing.

How does the game progress affect your entities? Your case (*a runner game*) suggests that the environment is constantly moving along one axis (left <> right, or up <> down). If this is true, this means that your wall points always spawn and despawn at the edges of the current environment. In such a case [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) is an ideal container to store your data.

Usually `std::vector` is a solid allrounder when it comes to container.

Always destroy your entities when you don't need them anymore. For example, if your wall points leave the view port (and you are sure they won't enter it again) remove them for the container.

## Putting Things Together

Considering everything I wrote above, your game loop could now like this:

```
int main() 
{        
    // Create window and init everything you need

    std::deque<WallPoint> wallPoints;
    // create some initial points

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // event handling
        }   

        // update game state
        // add new wall points
        // remove old points
        // move the player

        // draw the new game state
        window.Clear();
        for (const auto& point : wallPoints)
            window.draw(point);
        window.draw(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i might try and learn some more C++ before diving into SFML